# Retrieve array element that caused a runtime warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

When I apply `numpy.exp` to an array of numbers I get the following runtime warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
```

Now I know that some value in this array caused the result of `exp` to overflow but I don't know which one (and this array has millions of entries).

Is there a way to make this runtime warning more verbose in a sense that it also displays the specific argument that caused the overflow (and more importantly its position in the input array)? I discovered [seterr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) and [seterrcall](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterrcall.html) however they don't seem to incorporate what *caused* the error (only what the error is about).

---

I know that - after encountering this warning - I could pass each value in the array separately to `exp` and watch out for the warning or that I could use [isfinite](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) to test the elements of `exp(array)`. However this implies messing with the actual code while I would prefer that numpy does this kind of things behind the scenes (being configured appropriately).

---

**Edit:** I was asked to post some code that reproduces the error. Here it is:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> array = numpy.zeros((10,), dtype=float)
>>> array[0] = 1.0e308
>>> numpy.exp(array)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
array([ inf,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.])
```

I would like to know that it was the element with index `0` that caused to overflow (not just that an overflow happened somewhere).

Comment: Can you post some of your code ? What have you done till now ?

Comment: I added a snippet that reproduces the scenario.

Comment: Try changing `dtype=float` to `dtype=float128` . @a_guest

Comment: @Jarvis Did you even read my question? 1. I want to know the index of the element that caused the runtime warning not a way around it. 2. Using `dtype=numpy.float128` doesn't prevent the overflow but I guess you already know that because you tried it before suggesting, of course.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is just that exp(1e308) is too big for float !

If you consider the exp function, knowing that `1.7976931348623157e+308` is the maximum value for a float, remove from your array all the value below `log(1.7976931348623157e+308) = 709`

Comment: Please read my question again. I want to know the index of the element in the array that caused the runtime warning not a way around the warning. I want to achieve this by configuring numpy rather than performing checks like [isfinite](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) (or `> log(1.7976931348623157e+308)`) manually myself.